# How does getting AAAA record for name server from same name server work?

Tags: dns, nameservers, dig

Doing `dig +short @ns1.google.com ns1.google.com AAAA` hits `ns1.google.com` to get IPv6 address for `ns1.google.com`.  From wireshark i can see that the query goes to IPv6 address `2001:4860:4802:32::a` which is something i'm actually looking for.

Question is how did `dig` figure out to which IPv6 address the query, to get the IP address of the name server, should be sent to?

May be i'm missing something very basic here.

Comment: Asking for `AAAA` records and using IPv6 transport are completely non correlated things. `dig` used IPv6 just because your box has IPv6 and is probably configured to prefer it. On linux, see `/etc/gai.conf`.

Comment: "how did dig figure out to which IPv6 address the query" By doing recursive queries, as explained in its manpage, for the `@` option: "When the supplied server argument is a hostname, dig resolves that name before querying that name server."

Comment: Regarding your first comment- i wasn't trying to figure out why ipv6 transport is used,  my bad for not putting it clearly.  Though thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

`dig` used the system DNS resolver,  which is 1.1.1.1 (Cloudflare's) to fetch A and AAAA records for `ns1.google.com` and then used those addresses (IPv6) to answer the query which is oddly AAAA in my case.

I had missed few packets in wireshark earlier,  here is the cleaner picture:

[image: Wireshark pic]

@patrick-mevzek: thanks for the pointer!